# construction of Gaussian measure with a given mean function and covariance kernel

Tags: reference-request, gaussian-measure

In a previous class we covered Gaussian processes and specified them by their mean functions and covariance kernels.

Is there a reference book that covers the construction of the corresponding Gaussian measure on the separable Banach space $C(K)$ where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (or other appropriate space)?

Comment: Did you ever find a nice reference for this?

Comment: @CBBAM Not yet unfortunately.